# Unable to make a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, vector, iterator

For the last two or three hours I have been wrestling with this problem without any luck. I am reading in the text and then trying to make an adjacency list with all vertices having a link to the adjacent vertices in the list. The vertex class look like this:

```
class Vertex {
private:
  std::vector<Vertex*> connPtrVertices;  // vector of vertices adjacent to this one
public:
  void addVertex(Vertex* vert) { connPtrVertices.push_back(vert); }
```

And in main.cpp I am trying to connect the vertices to each other like this:

```
Vertex *v1, *v2;
v2->addVertex(v1);    // connect v2 to v1 
v1->addVertex(v2);    // connect v1 to v2
```

I am getting a Debug Assertion Failed message which is:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector
Line: 240

Expression: vector iterators incompatible
```

I have no clue what to do, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
The first time through the loop I am assigning v1 and v2 with new but then the second time I check if they exist and if they do I assign a pointer to Vertex like this:

```
v1 = &(p_graph->getVertex(vert1));
```

The method that is called is this:

```
Vertex Graph::getVertex(std::string v) {         // gets the vertex 
  for (std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++) {
     if ((it->getName()).compare(v) == 0)
        return *it;  // if strings are the same return vertex
    }
    exit(1);
 }
```

Is this where the mistake is?

Comment: you never initialized Vertex v1 or v2.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger, and please post the relevant code.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't complete (nor minimal, nor self-consistent), and we don't know what line 240 is, so it's impossible to tell whether the problem is that `vertices` isn't really a `vector<Vertex>`, or something else entirely. When you ask a question, prepare a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org), and when you write code, build up slowly from the simple to the complex, testing at every step.

Answer (score 0):

- Its seems that you are just trying to compile this code. Now, if you build the project, does it Build without a compiler error? What about debugging? you can try, "Start without Debugging". This will execute your code without debugging.
- The error message you are getting says: "vector iterators incompatible"
- This error is coming from where you wrote an iterator and its seems to be in Graph::getVertex(std::string v) function. To confirm it`s this function, you can comment out the whole Graph::getVertex(std::string v) function definition and see if the error disappears.
- To fix the iterator error "incompatible type" you can declare your iterator with typedef like this:
- typedef std::vector "<"Vertex">" VertexType;
- VertexType vertices;
- Vertex Graph::getVertex(std::string v) {
- VertexType::iterator it;
- for (it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it){
- return *it;
- }
- exit(1);
- }
- Make sure your iterator is pointing to Vertex object type.